# Laravel strftime with Homestead ain't working

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-4, strftime

I've been having alot of trouble with formating a date with my localization using Laravel and Homestead (I don't know if homestead has any kinda server configurations which make it doesn't work but thats my though). I guess anyone around the internet have been struggling with the same issue. I've been searching for an answer for hours without getting anywhere closer to a solution.. This is my code.

```
public function formated_start()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE');
    return strftime('%A %H:%M', strtotime($this->start));
}
```

I've also tried with laravel specific

```
public function formated_start()
{
    App::setLocale('sv_SE')
    return strftime('%A %H:%M', strtotime($this->start));
}
```

Still with the same result nothing changed and the %A which should be the day of week in my language in this case Swedish is still in English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Homestead provides an Ubuntu system. So first check which locales are available on your system with `locale -a`. Maybe the swedish locale is named `sv_SE.iso88591` or `sv_SE.utf8`. If it is not installed you can install it with:

```
sudo locale-gen sv_SE sv_SE.utf8
```

After installing your first solution with `setlocale();` should work. This would be the **PHP-way** to generate dates.

Don't forget to restart the server after you've installed the locale's described

```
sudo nginx restart
```

**The Laravel-way**

For the **Laravel-way** you need to generate the locals yourself. Start by adding a locale file in `/app/lang/sv/days.php` with:

```
<?php

return array(
    'Monday' => 'måndag',
    'Tuesday' => 'tisdag',
    'Wednesday' => '..',
    'Thursday' => '..',
    'Friday' => '..',
    'Saturday' => 'lördag',
    'Sunday' => '..',
);
```

Now you can use the `App::setLocale()` with `Lang::get()`:

```
App::setLocale('sv');
echo Lang::get(sprintf('days.%s', date('l')));
```

This is way more complex but if you are hosting Laravel on a shared hosting environment where you can't generate locales, this could be a possible way.

Comment: I will try this out, thanks alot for your time.
Just a comment this is not a 100% answer to my question since this ain't solving the problem with strftime, this is some kinda sneaky way around the strftime. So with this solution I need to ad the Hour and Minute to the string before I return the value, can you please edit your answer to a answer of strftime and I will probably mark your answer as accepted when I've tried this out.

Comment: This code (http://laravel.io/bin/wG1O0) make the correct output but still not with strftime and I think personally strftime is a better function to work with if I just could get this damn locales to work. Do you have any ideas of why it aint working?

Comment: I saw that I were missing the locales as you told me to add. But still doesn't work with the PHP-way so to speak

Comment: After using `sudo locale-gen sv_SE` what does the output of `locale -a` tells you?

Comment: After I did that those were added: 
sv_SE
sv_SE.iso88591
sv_SE.utf8

Comment: Ok. Please restart your web server: `sudo nginx restart`.

Comment: Holy Macaroni that made it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me at least in Windows.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE', 'Swedish', 'swedish');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is in general, instead of specifically using **strftime** you could try with [Laravel4-lang](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel4-lang), it's installed via composer.
Add to the `composer.json` file:

`"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "caouecs/laravel4-lang": "dev-master"
    },`

Then update the package:

`composer update caouecs/laravel4-lang`

**Update**

This worked really good too:
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-date